# open() method doesn't open specified .txt file

Tags: python, replit

I am made a file where i can reference functions and i thought that it would be fun to make a program to add text to the file, and when i try to open the file, it doesn't show any errors, but when i go and check the file there's nothing there.
My code:

```
ime_funk = input("Ime funkcije: ")
x = 0
funk = ""
while True:
    vseb_funk = input("Kopiraj eno, pa po eno vrstico funkcije, ko si končal napiši končano: ")
    if vseb_funk == "končano":
          break
    else:
        funk += "\n    "+vseb_funk

mark = open("test.txt", "a")
mark.write("\n" + ime_funk + "\n" + funk)
```

Don't pay attention to the variable names and strings, as that's not important.
Also I am using replit if that's important.
I have no idea why it doesn't work.
i have tried `mark = open("test.txt", "w")` but same story.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line to your code

```
mark.close()
```

or what you can do I replace this part of the code

```
mark = open("test.txt", "a")
mark.write("\n" + ime_funk + "\n" + funk)
```

with this code:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as mark:
   mark.write("\n" + ime_funk + "\n" + funk)
```

Answer (score 0):

A file write in python does not happen untill you call `file.flush()`. This is usually called automatically when you close the file but in your example you are never closing the file. Try:

```py
ime_funk = input("Ime funkcije: ")
x = 0
funk = ""
while True:
    vseb_funk = input("Kopiraj eno, pa po eno vrstico funkcije, ko si končal napiši končano: ")
    if vseb_funk == "končano":
          break
    else:
        funk += "\n    "+vseb_funk

mark = open("test.txt", "a")
mark.write("\n" + ime_funk + "\n" + funk)
mark.close()
```

or even better try using the `with` statement:

```py
with open("test.txt", "a") as mark:
    mark.write("\n" + ime_funk + "\n" + funk)
```

this way `close()` is called automatically